# Как забрать все данные из List в ListBox в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox

У меня есть класс

`

```
public partial class ArtistInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("artist")]
        public ArtistInfoArtist Artist { get; set; }
    }
```

`

В нём много полей из которых один

```
[JsonProperty("similar")]
public Similar Similar { get; set; }
```

А это класс

```
public partial class Similar
    {
        [JsonProperty("artist")]
        public List<ArtistElement> Artist { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот из этого класса мне надо забрать всю коллекцию и отобразить в ListBox.

Я попытался сделать так

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist.Similar.Artist}"/>
```

Но у меня выводится (Collection)

Как можно вывести все данные в ListBox именно из метода Artist в классе Similar?

Comment: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Artist}" />`, хотите больше - давайте больше информации, ибо дать нам одну строчку кода и просить что либо извините, бред.

Comment: Лучше я это добавлю в вопрос

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, добавьте в него (кнопка править под вопросом), сейчас у вас уже как видите "много классов" появились не пойми от куда. Поймите одну простейшую вещь, мы не знаем кто вы, мы не знаем как вы программируете (ваш стиль), мы не знаем ваш код, мы не знаем что у вас за проект и все, что мы знаем - это `public List<ArtistElement> Artist { get; set; }` и то, что его надо отобразить в `ListBox`, все. Как мы по вашему на основе этих данных можем вам помочь? Ок, ответ выше, привязывайте, выводите, пробуйте, либо давайте нам **все**, что необходимо для понятия вашей задачи.

Comment: Всё. Я добавил подробности о коде  как смог. Надеюсь что это вам поможет понять  меня.

Comment: Вот, уже лучше, впредь помните, что вы задаете вопрос людям, которые совершенно нечего не знаю про вас и ваш проект. По поводу вопроса: WPF отображает по умолчанию string привязанного объекта, у вас 2 варианта: 1. Переопределить `ToString` у класса `ArtistElement`, выведя там все необходимые свойства. 2. Переопределить шаблон `ListBoxItem`, прописав там все нужные свойства (более правильный способ).

Comment: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Artist.Similar.Artist}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>`

Вот так написал и ничего.

Comment: Что значит "ничего"? У вас установлен `DataContext`? Если да, то на какой класс, и есть ли в нем инициализированное свойство `ArtistInfo`?

Comment: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Artist}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist.Similar.Artist[0].Name}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>`

Смог вывести только ОДНО имя. А там лист. Как можно именно весь список вывети?